# How to update the External Content Type of existing column

Tags: 2016, column, external-content-type, update

I have a list with multiple columns as the type of External Data.

There are some changes in the External Content Type. so I want to update the reference for some of the columns.

But I am not able to do so. As **the External Data Item Picker is disabled**. There is no option to choose the external content type **when I edit the column.**

How can I achieve the above?

Thanks in Advance.